# Django - UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, django

I have a function in a view that I am using to upload CSV data and write to a DB. That part is working. However, when I try to check if there was data updated or created, I am getting an error which reads:

> "*local variable 'created' referenced before assignment*".

The function in the view is as follows

```
def bookings_upload(request):

    prompt = {
        'order': "Please import a valid CSV file"
    }
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'booking_app/importBookings.html', prompt)

    csv_file = request.FILES['bookings']

    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, "This file is not a .csv file.")
        return redirect('/booking_app/bookings_upload/') 

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)

    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
        _, created = Bookings.objects.update_or_create(
            book_date=column[0],
            grower_number=column[1],
            bales_booked=column[3],
            sale_date=column[6],
            book_id=column[11],
            reoffer=column[12]
        )
    ) 

    if created:
        messages.success(request, "Bookings have been imported successfully")
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "No new bookings were imported. Please check/verify your csv file")   

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'booking_app/importBookings.html', context)
```

What am I missing? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: move `if created` one step under the for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you read nothing from the csv file you will not define `created`. Try adding the following before you start the loop:

```
created = None
```

However, as BearBrown has suggested, this will solve your error, but you will still have a logic error. In order to fix both use the following code. This will show a message for each row:

```
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    _, created = Bookings.objects.update_or_create(
        book_date=column[0],
        grower_number=column[1],
        bales_booked=column[3],
        sale_date=column[6],
        book_id=column[11],
        reoffer=column[12]
    ) 

    if created:
        messages.success(request, "Bookings have been imported successfully")
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "No new bookings were imported. Please check/verify your csv file")
```

If you want to show just one general message:

```
created = None
created_records = 0

for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    _, created = Bookings.objects.update_or_create(
        book_date=column[0],
        grower_number=column[1],
        bales_booked=column[3],
        sale_date=column[6],
        book_id=column[11],
        reoffer=column[12]
    )

    if created:
        created_records += 1



if created is None:
    messages.success(request, "No records were read from file.")
elif created_records > 0:
    messages.success(request, f"{created_records} bookings have been imported successfully")
else:
    messages.warning(request, "No new bookings were imported. Please check/verify your csv file")
```

The previous code assumes you use Python 3.6+, if using a previous version, change this line:

```
messages.success(request, f"{created_records} bookings have been imported
```

to:

```
messages.success(request, "{created_records} bookings have been imported successfully".format(created_records=created_records))
```

Comment: I get what you mean @lmiguelvargasf and I have just modified the test csv file and uploaded to test and the code worked. How best can I circumvent this issue in the event that there is nothing to be read from the CSV?

Comment: @BearBrown, what do you mean? I thought the main problem was the `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: if in the file will be many rows you the `messages` will get result only for last

Comment: @BearBrown, gotta you. I will add that and mention you in the update.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf thanks for that. This solved my issue. But I see there is something BearBrown mentioned that you just concurred with. Care to share?

Comment: There is an extra ) in your updated answer @Imiguelvargasf

Comment: @TonyCarter, good catch, updated. I also updated the indentation

Comment: The version, as edited, will now show a message for each row, which is _also_ not what the OP wants.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Still no dice. The message will now reflect the state of the _last_ record imported.

Comment: @AKX, you are right, I just updated my answer using your suggestion. Thanks man.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf in your updated answer, aren't you supposed to put an if statement to check if a new record was created?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf all is in order now. I have also upvoted your answer as I have a 15+ reputation now. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: you're welcome @TonyCarter. I am glad I could help you.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can validate an answer (green checkmark) that is another way to thank people who helped you if your the answered solved your problem.

Comment: How do you green checkmark an answer? Does it come with reputation score or it's somewhere?

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) you have more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

@lmiguelvargasf's answer explains what's happening, but I'd reckon a better refactoring, that also adds more information, would be:

```py
n_created = 0
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=",", quotechar="|"):
    _, created = Bookings.objects.update_or_create(
        book_date=column[0],
        grower_number=column[1],
        bales_booked=column[3],
        sale_date=column[6],
        book_id=column[11],
        reoffer=column[12],
    )
    if created:
        n_created += 1

if n_created:
    messages.success(request, "%d bookings have been imported successfully" % n_created)
else:
    messages.warning(request, "No new bookings were imported. Please check/verify your csv file")
```